# iOS memory management property

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory

It's a MRC project, is there a problem of over release? Because the property `welcomeLabel` has not been invoked, I just used the variable `_welcomeLabel`.

Here's the code:

```
@interface MyViewController ()

 @property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *welcomeLabel;

@end

@implementation

- (void)dealloc {

    [_welcomeLabel release];

    [super dealloc];

}

- (void)viewDidLoad {

    _welcomeLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 60, 40)] autorelease];

    [self.view addSubView:_welcomeLabel];

}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since you don't use the property setter the refcount won't get increased. The refcount will remain at 1 and you release it twice one time in when the autorelease pool gets drained and once in dealloc.

Comment: Thanks. However, if I don't release it in the method -(void)dealloc,I am afraid there will be a memory leak, so I am confused.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't think so, I think about it for a long time, but have no idea.

Comment: Why do you need the autorelease?